# Android studio 4.1.2 + Kotlin 1.4.30 error: "Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ..."

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading kotlin from 1.4.21 to 1.4.30 my project build fails with this (folded) error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:consumerDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
DefaultDomainObjectSet#add(T) on [Signature app:aar.asc:asc:null] cannot be executed in the current context.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:consumerDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
DefaultDomainObjectSet#add(T) on [Signature app:aar.asc:asc:null] cannot be executed in the current context.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:273)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:131)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:56)
org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:consumerDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ConstraintHandler.execute(ConstraintHandler.kt:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ConstraintHandler.execute(ConstraintHandler.kt:39)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ConstraintHandler.execute(ConstraintHandler.kt:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ConstraintHandler.execute(ConstraintHandler.kt:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KotlinJvmCompilerArgumentsContributor.contributeArguments(CompilerArgumentsContributor.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KotlinJvmCompilerArgumentsContributor.contributeArguments(CompilerArgumentsContributor.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.setupCompilerArgs(Tasks.kt:502)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.setupCompilerArgs(Tasks.kt:465)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.setupCompilerArgs$default(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareKt.prepareCompilerArguments(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareKt.prepareCompilerArguments$default(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.getSerializedCompilerArguments(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareWithInput$DefaultImpls.getSerializedCompilerArguments(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompileTool.getSerializedCompilerArguments(Tasks.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile_Decorated.getSerializedCompilerArguments(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.KotlinGradleModelBuilder.getCompilerArguments(KotlinGradleModelBuilder.kt:126)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.KotlinGradleModelBuilder.buildAll(KotlinGradleModelBuilder.kt:176)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.KotlinGradleModelBuilder.buildAll(KotlinGradleModelBuilder.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder.buildAll(ExtraModelBuilder.java:104)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction$MyBuildController.findModel(ProjectImportAction.java:549)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ClassSetProjectImportModelProvider.populateProjectModels(ClassSetProjectImportModelProvider.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addProjectModels(ProjectImportAction.java:216)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractMutationGuard$IllegalMutationException: DefaultDomainObjectSet#add(T) on [Signature app:aar.asc:asc:null] cannot be executed in the current context.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractMutationGuard.createIllegalStateException(AbstractMutationGuard.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractMutationGuard.assertMutationAllowed(AbstractMutationGuard.java:27)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.assertMutable(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:452)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:251)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.add(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:110)
    at org.gradle.plugins.signing.SigningExtension$12.execute(SigningExtension.java:456)
    at org.gradle.plugins.signing.SigningExtension$12.execute(SigningExtension.java:453)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SingletonSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:225)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:264)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:253)
    at org.gradle.plugins.signing.Sign.addSignature(Sign.java:171)
    at org.gradle.plugins.signing.Sign.signArtifact(Sign.java:104)
    at org.gradle.plugins.signing.Sign.lambda$sign$3(Sign.java:136)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$FilteredAction.execute(Actions.java:245)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SingletonSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:225)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.DefaultCollectionEventRegister.fireObjectAdded(DefaultCollectionEventRegister.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet$1.execute(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:113)
    at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SingletonSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:225)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAddRealized(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:274)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.access$000(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection$1.execute(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.AbstractIterationOrderRetainingElementSource$Element.realize(AbstractIterationOrderRetainingElementSource.java:323)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.AbstractIterationOrderRetainingElementSource$Element.getValues(AbstractIterationOrderRetainingElementSource.java:341)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.IterationOrderRetainingSetElementSource.clearCachedElement(IterationOrderRetainingSetElementSource.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.AbstractIterationOrderRetainingElementSource.lambda$cachingElement$1(AbstractIterationOrderRetainingElementSource.java:162)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.ChangingValueHandler.handle(ChangingValueHandler.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultArtifactPublicationSet$DefaultArtifactProvider.addArtifact(DefaultArtifactPublicationSet.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultArtifactPublicationSet.addCandidate(DefaultArtifactPublicationSet.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin.lambda$configureConfigurations$5(BasePlugin.java:162)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$2.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SingletonSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:225)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:264)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:253)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.add(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:110)
    at org.gradle.plugins.signing.SigningExtension$12.execute(SigningExtension.java:456)
    at org.gradle.plugins.signing.SigningExtension$12.execute(SigningExtension.java:453)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SingletonSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:225)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:264)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:253)
    at org.gradle.plugins.signing.Sign.addSignature(Sign.java:171)
    at org.gradle.plugins.signing.Sign.signArtifact(Sign.java:104)
    at org.gradle.plugins.signing.Sign.lambda$sign$3(Sign.java:136)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$FilteredAction.execute(Actions.java:245)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SingletonSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:225)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.DefaultCollectionEventRegister.fireObjectAdded(DefaultCollectionEventRegister.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet$1.execute(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:113)
    at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SingletonSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:225)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAddRealized(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:274)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.access$000(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection$1.execute(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.AbstractIterationOrderRetainingElementSource$Element.realize(AbstractIterationOrderRetainingElementSource.java:323)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.AbstractIterationOrderRetainingElementSource.realizePending(AbstractIterationOrderRetainingElementSource.java:131)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.IterationOrderRetainingSetElementSource.iterator(IterationOrderRetainingSetElementSource.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.iterator(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:130)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.iterator(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.component.local.model.DefaultLocalComponentMetadata.addArtifacts(DefaultLocalComponentMetadata.java:146)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultLocalComponentMetadataBuilder$1.visitArtifacts(DefaultLocalComponentMetadataBuilder.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationPublications.collectVariants(DefaultConfigurationPublications.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.collectVariants(DefaultConfiguration.java:1039)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultLocalComponentMetadataBuilder.addConfiguration(DefaultLocalComponentMetadataBuilder.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.addConfiguration(DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.getRootComponentMetadata(DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.java:96)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.lambda$buildRootComponentMetadata$0(DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:277)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.buildRootComponentMetadata(DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.toRootComponentMetaData(DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.toRootComponentMetaData(DefaultConfiguration.java:1181)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$DefaultResolveContextToComponentResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:178)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$1.call(DefaultConfiguration.java:643)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$1.call(DefaultConfiguration.java:634)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:634)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.lambda$resolveExclusively$4(DefaultConfiguration.java:614)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$CalculatedModelValueImpl.update(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:362)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveExclusively(DefaultConfiguration.java:611)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:598)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1900(DefaultConfiguration.java:149)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationResolvableDependencies$LenientResolutionResult.resolve(DefaultConfiguration.java:1775)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationResolvableDependencies$LenientResolutionResult.allDependencies(DefaultConfiguration.java:1800)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ConstraintHandler.execute(ConstraintHandler.kt:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ConstraintHandler.execute(ConstraintHandler.kt:39)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ConstraintHandler.execute(ConstraintHandler.kt:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ConstraintHandler.execute(ConstraintHandler.kt:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KotlinJvmCompilerArgumentsContributor.contributeArguments(CompilerArgumentsContributor.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KotlinJvmCompilerArgumentsContributor.contributeArguments(CompilerArgumentsContributor.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.setupCompilerArgs(Tasks.kt:502)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.setupCompilerArgs(Tasks.kt:465)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.setupCompilerArgs$default(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareKt.prepareCompilerArguments(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareKt.prepareCompilerArguments$default(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.getSerializedCompilerArguments(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareWithInput$DefaultImpls.getSerializedCompilerArguments(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompileTool.getSerializedCompilerArguments(Tasks.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile_Decorated.getSerializedCompilerArguments(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.KotlinGradleModelBuilder.getCompilerArguments(KotlinGradleModelBuilder.kt:126)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.KotlinGradleModelBuilder.buildAll(KotlinGradleModelBuilder.kt:176)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.KotlinGradleModelBuilder.buildAll(KotlinGradleModelBuilder.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder.buildAll(ExtraModelBuilder.java:104)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction$MyBuildController.findModel(ProjectImportAction.java:549)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ClassSetProjectImportModelProvider.populateProjectModels(ClassSetProjectImportModelProvider.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addProjectModels(ProjectImportAction.java:216)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I checked all the dependencies and repositories, but nothing seems out of order...
Cleaning and rebuilding doesn't help nor does invalidating the cache.
I tried to upgrade Gradle from 6.5 to 6.8.2, but that didn't help either.

It looks like it's related to signing the extensions, but I didn't find anything mentioned about that in the release notes so I'm at a loss.
For now I can stick with 1.4.21, but can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Cheers

---

## Update

I seems that I don't have any archives to sign (which would explain the **null** in `[Signature app:aar.asc:asc:null]`) and this makes the build crash when using

```
signing {
    sign configurations.archives
}
```

Removing this line fixes the issue when using kotlin 1.4.30, but how does this all make sense as the signing is a gradle feature (using Groovy)?

Comment: upload your gradle files